# How was the first calculation of the g-factor done?

Tags: physics

Dirac said the magnetic g-factor (a measure of the electron's wiggling in a magnetic field) is exactly 2. Quantum field theory introduced a g-factor that diverged a bit from 2. It needs an increasing amount of Feynmann diagrams to calculate its value. Every diagram is a calculation an Sich. The fine structure constant is involved in this. I have never quite understood how the g-factor can be calculated without a precise value of this structure constant but that aside. How were the calculations done (the first calculation was done in 1947)? There were no mainframes in sight yet but there *was* this room-filling behemoth. Was this used? Were the calculations done by hand (maybe with an advanced abacus)? I think that we can say one thing is certain: they werent't done from the head.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean "How was the first calculation of the *anomalous* g-factor done?"

Comment: @Mauricio Yes. Though I think the g=2 is the anomalous one. Thats how theý are normally called, but my personal view.